# iPython in Emacs split window cannot stay where they are

Tags: emacs, split

I would like to fix the split window in the following way. But when I press `C-c C-c`, the way how it splits changed to the second picture. How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the `C-c C-c` keybinding is supposed to do for you (and I've never used IPython mode), but from https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Split-Window.html:

> C-x 3 (split-window-right) splits the selected window into two side-by-side windows. The left window is the selected one; the right window displays the same portion of the same buffer, and has the same value of point. A positive numeric argument specifies how many columns to give the left window; a negative numeric argument specifies how many columns to give the right window.

You can then switch to the newly opened windowed by typing `C-x o` and find the file you want to open with `C-x C-f`.

Comment: Thanks. But does not fix the problem. I switched to elpy in python-mode.   It seems to be okay.